# PHP MySQL query with condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, conditional-operator

I got stuck with a simple query which I can't figure out why isn't doing what I expect it to do. I have 3 values set on database like this:

```
$measure = 'kg';
$country_code = 'DE';
$weight = '5';

WEIGHT_UNIT | COUNTRIES | MAX_WEIGHT | PRICE
kg          | DE,AT     | 10         | 25.55
lbs         | DE,AT,CH  | 5          | 15.99
```

My PHP query looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `article_shipping_options`
WHERE `weight_unit` = '$measure'
    AND `countries` LIKE '%$country_code%'
    AND `max_weight` <= '$weight'
LIMIT 1;
```

The result I was expecting was the row with the 25.55 price.

I know I am doing something wrong here despise my 2 days search on google...any help would be mostly appreciated :)

Comment: `var_dump(10 <= 5); // return false`

Comment: then what is result of query?

Comment: Don't store comma separated values in a single database column if you're going to use it for querying.

Comment: Could you do a `DESCRIBE table_name` and paste the results?

Comment: @ypercube, I did read wiki from `QUERY` atg and it says, `A request to retrieve information from a database or other information system. This tag can be used to refer to SQL queries against a database (SQL-Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc.) ` so I added it here. The last question was a mistake.

Comment: @Jack: result is 0 rows

Comment: is `AND max_weight <= '$weight'` a typo?
it should be `AND max_weight >= '$weight'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean `MAX_WEIGHT >= $weight` ?

Comment: but if the operator WAS the issue, it would be a solution.

Comment: SOLUTION: then you might have defined the max_weight field as a numerical field in which case you should remove the quotation marks around the $weight variable? – by mavili under matt post.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the wrong inequality operator. Shouldn't it be `max_weight >= '$weight'`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, I've tried that too with no success. This thing is just driving me crazy :D I used operators alot in the past but this is the first time I got stuck like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `FIND_IN_SET()` and use `max_weight >= '$weight'`

```
SELECT * 
FROM   article_shipping_options 
WHERE  weight_unit='$measure' AND 
       FIND_IN_SET($country_code, countries) > 0  AND 
       max_weight >= '$weight' 
LIMIT  1;
```

- [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I appreciate it! Unfortunatelly FIND_INT_SET does the same thing as my query is doing. I think the problem lies on the operator part.

Answer (score 0):

You have `$weight` set to 5, but in the row's `MAX_HEIGHT` is 10.

Then the last condition for that row evaluates as `10 <= 5`. Since the condition was not met, the row was not returned.

Comment: Yes, I've tries that too...no success so far :(

Comment: then you might have defined the `max_weight` field as a numerical field in which case you should remove the quotation marks around the `$weight` variable?

Comment: BINGO! Thank you so much! I can't believe I did such stupid error. I've paid half of my sunday for it but thanks to you I can rest a bit now!

Comment: @everybody: Thank you all for trying to help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Jay so what was your problem??

Comment: @mavili: the quotation was the problem. That was the only thing messing up my query statement. After removing it, all worked just fine. Thanks alot for pointing that out!

Comment: but you've marked the solution from @matt as the answer to your problem. which is not the case ?